# Explicitly set true Bool is somehow set to false

Tags: swift

Do the following:

Create a class called `A`, subclass of `UITableViewCell`:

```
class A: UITableViewCell {
    var isChosen: Bool = true
}
```

Create a xib file and drag a `UITableViewCell` object as the top level object, and make sure to set its class to `A`:

[image]  [image]

Create an instance of `A`:

```
var a = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("A", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as A
```

Print `isChosen`:

```
println(a.isChosen)
```

Output:

```
false
```

Why is this happening? It only happens when you initialize the instance from a nib.

Even if you declare the variable as an optional and set it to `nil`:

```
var isChosen: Bool! = nil
```

it'll *still* be set to `false` somehow.

Comment: As a fix/workaround, mark your A as [@IBInspectable](http://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/) — you can then choose its initial value right in Interface Builder. It'll appear at the top of the Attributes inspector, and you can set "is Chosen" to be "ON". This value will be set on your A instance when it's warmed up from the nib. This rather cool new Interface Builder functionality seems pretty much designed for your needs.

Comment: This thread https://devforums.apple.com/message/979480#979480 in the Apple Developer Forum mentions the same problem, see in particular reply #7 (developer login required).

Comment: I *think* it's fixed in beta 5. You can override initWithCoder in A, and just call the superclass implementation. isChosen seems to come through as true. (Caveat: it's late and I'm tired so I might have missed something :) )

Comment: @MattGibson, you are completely right! I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since your class `A` does not have any init methods defined swift automatically generated default initializer for you. With default `init()` method code `var isChosen: Bool = true` is a shortcut to:

```
class A: UITableViewCell {
    var isChosen: Bool

    init() {
        isChosen = true
    }
}
```

When you create your custom cell of type `A` from Nib then auto generated `init()` method does not get called because `initWithCoder` called hence `isChosen` value is `false`.

---

**UPDATE:**

As already mentioned by @MattGibson in comments to the question, with **xCode 6 Beta 5** update we can address the problem. It can be solved by adding `init with coder` initializer and  marking it as required, so `A` should contain code bellow:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

How it works? From Beta 5 Release Notes:

> The required modifier is written before every subclass implementation
>   of a required initializer. Required initializers can be satisfied by
>   automatically inherited initializers.

**UPDATE:**

`required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) { ... }` should be added only if you override at lest one `init` method in your class.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this behaviour. Tried this in a playground: https://gist.github.com/gothick/0e145487f224194f636a and it doesn't seem to behave as you describe. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Keenie this would explain why it's not true, but it wouldn't explain why it's false. If anything, it should just be nil.

Comment: @moby Nope; it can't be nil. This is Swift; if a Bool isn't Optional it can only be true or false. I can't quite figure out what's going on, and I think that Keenie is right, and that it's due to being warmed up from a nib through initWithCoder, but I don't know enough about the internals of that or Swift to convince myself of exactly what's going on.

Comment: @MattGibson even if it were declared as an optional, the resulting value would be `Optional(false)` instead of `nil`.

Comment: @MattGibson, you code returns true because you have not defined any initializer in A. So A inherits all init methods from Base and sets isChosen to true before calling any of base init methods, this gets done automatically by swift. Try to remove '=true' in isChosen definition then override Base class initializer and ommit initializion of isChosen, swift will raise an error; such error emphasize tells developer to perform initialization manualy it once decided to redefine init method(s).

Comment: "So A inherits all init methods from Base and sets isChosen to true before calling any of base init methods, this gets done automatically by swift" If that's the case, isn't that then what should happen with the original poster's example? His A has no init methods, either.

Comment: @MattGibson, yes it has no init methods but initWithCoder is not an init method, it is just a method in NSCoding protocol. So swift is not obligated to handle initialization in case of initWithCoder.

Comment: @moby, I agree that having bool value implicitly set to `false` is unexpected behaviour, especially for swift. You can fill a bug or may be better raise this question(why swift automatically sets bool to false?) at apple developer forums. I think this is kind of exceptional case with swift that is still in beta, and you've found it!

Comment: @Keenle Yeah, it's a bit odd. I'd think that if you wanted to handle this manually, you'd add an implementation of initWithCoder to A, and call the superclass's initWithCoder, then set your own isChosen up yourself. I think that would work in Objective C. However, in Swift, you can't have an initialiser that doesn't call the superclass's designated initialiser (which is `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)` in this case) and you can't *also* call the superclass's `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!)` as you can't call *two* `super.init` methods...

Comment: @MattGibson, as Martin R mentioned in comment to the question, Apple knows about this problem. And I agree that it is a problem, so I hope they fix it soon.

Comment: Hah! I'm an idiot. I read the Apple thread a couple of days ago, and I have to say I didn't really get it. Then I just spent a bunch of time today poking around and learning about NSCoding  and basically figured it out for myself. What I hadn't done was re-read the devforums thread and worked out that it said exactly what I'd just spent ages figuring out :) My apologies! Learning is sometimes hard.